# How can I define a variable and then use it in multiple hotkeys?

Tags: autohotkey

#### Example

```
#Persistent
fileName = H:\Data\Desktop\myfile.txt
return

^#Left::
FileDelete, %fileName%
return

^#Right::
FileDelete, %fileName%
FileAppend, %clipboard%, %fileName%
return
```

Right now it works with the `#Persistent` command but I have to put the `#Persistent` at the top of the file, which is inconvenient. If I remove the Persistent, it stops working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, apparently superuser is not the place to ask `autohotkey` questions :)

The [autohotkey forum](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/) (archived; [new forum here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/)) is quite active and I found the answer on the first search (Asked and answered yesterday). In my defense: Google didn't give me any relevant answer even after multiple search attempts.

> maul.esel: Only the Global variables in the function you need:

```
globalVar := "abc"
func()
{
    Global globalVar
    MsgBox %globalVar%
}
```

> Latest AHK supports so-called "super-globals":

```
global globalVar := "abc"
func()
{
    MsgBox %globalVar%
}
```

The original thread: [globals not global](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/86273-globals-not-global/page__hl__global%20variable#entry549346)